# How to go from enum tp byte array and back again?

Tags: java

I have an enum

```
public enum Test {
  VALUE, NAME;
}
```

I convert it into a byte array

```
byte[] array = Test.VALUE.toString().getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8)
```

how can i convert that back into an enum?

`Test.valueOf(array.toString())` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `array.toString` didn't work is that `toString` returns a description of the array, not the string constructed using the bytes in the array with UTF-8 encoding. `toString` just returns something like `[B@60e53b93` which means practically nothing to humans.

To convert a byte array to a string, use the string's constructor, the one that takes a byte array and a `Charset`. Here's the whole code:

```
// converting to byte array
Test t = Test.VALUE;
byte[] bytes = t.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// converting back to Test
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Test newT = Test.valueOf(str);
```

If you think about it logically, `toString` can't possibly give you what you expect. This is because to convert a byte array to a string, you need to specify an encoding! You obvious did not pass a `Charset` object when you call `toString`, so how on earth is the computer going to know what charset you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the array back to a proper `String` first using it constructor. `array.toString()` does not do what you think and will only return gibberish.

```
byte[] array = Test.VALUE.toString().getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
String valueString = new String(array, Charsets.UTF_8);
Test value = Test.valueOf(valueString);
```